# How to combine Pulse Sensor to send Telegram message with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

Hey I'm trying to have an arduino send a message through telegram when the pulse detected is over a range of given numbers. I have the pulsesensor.ino and telegram.ino working, but I have no idea where to go to combine the two. Here's the code

PULSE SENSOR

`/*

```
   Code to detect heartbeat pulses from the PulseSensor


   Check out the PulseSensor Playground Tools for explaination
   of all user functions and directives.
   https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground/blob/master/resources/PulseSensor%20Playground%20Tools.md


   Copyright World Famous Electronics LLC - see LICENSE
   Contributors:
     Joel Murphy, https://pulsesensor.com
     Yury Gitman, https://pulsesensor.com
     Bradford Needham, @bneedhamia, https://bluepapertech.com


   Licensed under the MIT License, a copy of which
   should have been included with this software.


   This software is not intended for medical use.
*/


/*
   Include the PulseSensor Playground library to get all the good stuff!
   The PulseSensor Playground library will decide whether to use
   a hardware timer to get accurate sample readings by checking
   what target hardware is being used and adjust accordingly.
   You may see a "warning" come up in red during compilation
   if a hardware timer is not being used.
*/


#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>


/*
   The format of our output.


   Set this to PROCESSING_VISUALIZER if you're going to run
    the Processing Visualizer Sketch.
    See https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensor_Amped_Processing_Visualizer


   Set this to SERIAL_PLOTTER if you're going to run
    the Arduino IDE's Serial Plotter.
*/
const int OUTPUT_TYPE = PROCESSING_VISUALIZER;


/*
   Pinout:
     PULSE_INPUT = Analog Input. Connected to the pulse sensor
      purple (signal) wire.
     PULSE_BLINK = digital Output. Connected to an LED (and 1K series resistor)
      that will flash on each detected pulse.
     PULSE_FADE = digital Output. PWM pin onnected to an LED (and 1K series resistor)
      that will smoothly fade with each pulse.
      NOTE: PULSE_FADE must be a pin that supports PWM. Do not use
      pin 9 or 10, because those pins' PWM interferes with the sample timer.
     THRESHOLD should be set higher than the PulseSensor signal idles
      at when there is nothing touching it. The expected idle value
      should be 512, which is 1/2 of the ADC range. To check the idle value
      open a serial monitor and make note of the PulseSensor signal values
      with nothing touching the sensor. THRESHOLD should be a value higher
      than the range of idle noise by 25 to 50 or so. When the library
      is finding heartbeats, the value is adjusted based on the pulse signal
      waveform. THRESHOLD sets the default when there is no pulse present.
      Adjust as neccesary.
*/
const int PULSE_INPUT = 36;
const int PULSE_BLINK = 13;
const int PULSE_FADE = 5;
const int THRESHOLD = 550;   // Adjust this number to avoid noise when idle


/*
   All the PulseSensor Playground functions.
*/
PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;


void setup() {
  /*
     Use 115200 baud because that's what the Processing Sketch expects to read,
     and because that speed provides about 11 bytes per millisecond.


     If we used a slower baud rate, we'd likely write bytes faster than
     they can be transmitted, which would mess up the timing
     of readSensor() calls, which would make the pulse measurement
     not work properly.
  */
  Serial.begin(115200);


  // Configure the PulseSensor manager.


  pulseSensor.analogInput(PULSE_INPUT);
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(PULSE_BLINK);
  pulseSensor.fadeOnPulse(PULSE_FADE);


  pulseSensor.setSerial(Serial);
  pulseSensor.setOutputType(OUTPUT_TYPE);
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(THRESHOLD);


  // Now that everything is ready, start reading the PulseSensor signal.
  if (!pulseSensor.begin()) {
    /*
       PulseSensor initialization failed,
       likely because our particular Arduino platform interrupts
       aren't supported yet.


       If your Sketch hangs here, try PulseSensor_BPM_Alternative.ino,
       which doesn't use interrupts.
    */
    for(;;) {
      // Flash the led to show things didn't work.
      digitalWrite(PULSE_BLINK, LOW);
      delay(50); Serial.println('!');
      digitalWrite(PULSE_BLINK, HIGH);
      delay(50);
    }
  }
}


void loop() {
   /*
     See if a sample is ready from the PulseSensor.


     If USE_HARDWARE_TIMER is true, the PulseSensor Playground
     will automatically read and process samples from
     the PulseSensor.


     If USE_HARDWARE_TIMER is false, the call to sawNewSample()
     will check to see how much time has passed, then read
     and process a sample (analog voltage) from the PulseSensor.
     Call this function often to maintain 500Hz sample rate,
     that is every 2 milliseconds. Best not to have any delay()
     functions in the loop when using a software timer.


     Check the compatibility of your hardware at this link
     <url>
     and delete the unused code portions in your saved copy, if you like.
  */
if(pulseSensor.UsingHardwareTimer){
  /*
     Wait a bit.
     We don't output every sample, because our baud rate
     won't support that much I/O.
  */
  delay(20);
  // write the latest sample to Serial.
  pulseSensor.outputSample();
} else {
/*
    When using a software timer, we have to check to see if it is time
    to acquire another sample. A call to sawNewSample will do that.
*/
  if (pulseSensor.sawNewSample()) {
    /*
        Every so often, send the latest Sample.
        We don't print every sample, because our baud rate
        won't support that much I/O.
    */
    if (--pulseSensor.samplesUntilReport == (byte) 0) {
      pulseSensor.samplesUntilReport = SAMPLES_PER_SERIAL_SAMPLE;
      pulseSensor.outputSample();
    }
  }
}
  /*
     If a beat has happened since we last checked,
     write the per-beat information to Serial.
   */
    if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) {
      pulseSensor.outputBeat();
    }
}
`
```

TELEGRAM

```
`
/*
 * This ESP32 code is created by esp32io.com
 *
 * This ESP32 code is released in the public domain
 *
 * For more detail (instruction and wiring diagram), visit https://esp32io.com/tutorials/esp32-http-request
 */

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <UrlEncode.h>
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>

const char WIFI_SSID[] = "OurHome";         // CHANGE IT         // CHANGE IT
const char WIFI_PASSWORD[] = "heroplace17"; // CHANGE IT
const int OUTPUT_TYPE = PROCESSING_VISUALIZER;
const int PULSE_INPUT = 36;
const int PULSE_BLINK = 13;
const int PULSE_FADE = 5;
const int THRESHOLD = 550;


PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;

//String PATH_NAME   = "/products/arduino.php";      // CHANGE IT
void loop() {
  
}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(Serial.available() == 0){
  }
  String message   =  "https://api.callmebot.com/whatsapp.php?phone=13026122697&text="+urlEncode("User's BPM exceeded the")+"&apikey=4645745";
  String HOST_NAME = message;
  Serial.print(HOST_NAME);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  HTTPClient http;

  http.begin(HOST_NAME); //HTTP
  int httpCode = http.GET();

  // httpCode will be negative on error
  if(httpCode > 0) {
    // file found at server
    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK) {
      String payload = http.getString();
      Serial.println(payload);
    } else {
      // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
    }
  } else {
    Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
  }

  http.end();
}


`
```

I tried combining them but honestly I don't know where to start.